# Calculating efficiency of rejection sampling

Tags: r, simulation

I have a joint distribution from which I want to simulate $f(x,y) = 2(1-x)(1-y)(1-xy)^{-3}, 0<x,y<1$.

I have worked out that the marginal distributions are both $U(0,1)$, so I want to simulate by first simulating $Y \sim U(0,1)$, then use rejection sampling to simulate $X$ from $f_{X|Y}$. I have used calculus to work out that for a given $y$, $f_{X|Y}$ is bounded above by $2(1-y)$ if $0<y<\frac{1}{3}$ and $f_{X|Y}$ is bounded above by $\frac{8/27}{y(1-y)}$ if $\frac{1}{3}<y<1$, so I use $U(0,1)$ as the proposal distribution and $M = 2(1-y) \text{ or } \frac{8/27}{y(1-y)}$, depending on $y$.

This seems to work, but I have a problem with calculating the efficiency of the sampling when $\frac{1}{3} < y < 1$, theoretically, it ought to be $\frac{3}{2} \int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{1} \frac{y(1-y)}{8/27} dy \approx 0.625$. However, when I implement it in R, the efficiency (only when $\frac{1}{3} < y < 1$) is approximately $0.2$. I don't understand why this is happening.

```
XY_pdf <- function(x,y) {
  
  return (2*(1-x)*(1-y)*((1-x*y)^(-3)))
}

simulate_XY <- function() {

  Y = (2/3)*runif(1) + (1/3)
  
  M = 0.296296/((Y)*(1-Y))
  
  candidate_X = runif(1)
  uniform_random_number = runif(1)
  
  counter = 1 
  
  while ((M)*uniform_random_number > XY_pdf(candidate_X, Y)) {
  candidate_X = runif(1)
  uniform_random_number = runif(1)
  counter = counter + 1
}
   
   return(list(candidate_X,Y,counter))
}
  
random_XY <- replicate(1000,simulate_XY())

X_values = unlist(random_XY[1,])
Y_values = unlist(random_XY[2,])
number_of_attempts = unlist(random_XY[3,])

my_df = data.frame(X_values, Y_values, number_of_attempts)

sum(my_df$number_of_attempts)
length(my_df$Y_values)
```

Comment: I think your $0.296296$ is actually $\frac{8}{27}$

Comment: @Henry Yes, it is. Thank you, I will edit that.

Comment: `Y <- (2/3)*runif(10^6) + (1/3); X <- runif(10^6); Z <- runif(10^6) * 8/27/Y/(1-Y);` `OK <- (Z < XY_pdf(X,Y)); mean(OK)` gives about $0.625$ (presumably $\frac58$) though this is not the right way to do it

Comment: @Henry What are you saying? Are you saying that my theoretical calculation (about 0.625) is correct but my empirical efficiency (0.2) is incorrect?

Comment: Not quite.  It says that the probability for a given $y \in [\frac13,1]$ a candidate $x$ would pass is $\frac{27y(1-y)}{8}$ and the average of that over the interval is $\frac58$.  But that is not what you are asking for.  Instead, I think the expected number of $x$ candidates needed for a given $y$ is $\frac{8}{27y(1-y)}$ and has an infinite average over that interval (the problem is with $y$ close to $1$) and you were lucky your empirical efficiency was as high as $0.2$. In a sense the distinction between an arithmetic mean and a harmonic mean

Comment: I suspect the expected ratio of accepted values to candidate values may be $\dfrac{1}{\frac{3}{2} \int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{1} \frac8{27y(1-y)} dy} = 0$

Comment: @Henry You are right, I understand now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't exactly answer the question, but it may be helpful to point out that if $u=\frac{y}{1-y}$ through a transformation of variables, then $u|x\sim\beta'(u;1,2,1,(1-x)^{-1})$, where $\beta'$ is the [generalized beta prime distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution#Generalization).

$u|x$ can be sampled by compounding two gamma distributions after sampling $x\sim{U(0,1)}$ (using the inverse scale parameterization for the gamma distribution):
$$r|x\sim\Gamma(2,(1-x)^{-1})$$
$$u|x\sim\Gamma(1,r)$$
From which we obtain samples of $y|x$ by:
$$y=\frac{u}{u+1}$$
Using this method to sample 1M pairs of $(x,y)$ in R:

```
x <- runif(1e6)
u <- rgamma(1e6, 1, rgamma(1e6, 2, 1/(1 - x)))
y <- u/(u + 1)
```